# Unable to use jenkins after restarting the pc

Tags: jenkins

I have installed the jenkins using jenkins.war file on windows, i have set up the plugins for it. But next day when i tried to open the jenkins on 192.168.43.75:8090. It is not working[image]

Comment: it all depends on how you started jenkins. Let me ask you this, if you open a notepad on your computer and then restart it, do your find it opened when your laptop is booted?

Comment: Now, i understand, i need to enter jenkins command, everytime i want to use jenkins

Answer (score 1):

did you run the war file again after your restart?

```
java -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=8090
```

[image]

Are you able to see **Jenkins is fully up and running** in the server logs?

If still issues persist then update the question with the server logs.

Comment: do I need to run the war file everytime after I restart my pc?

Comment: You can install it as a windows service .

Answer (score 1):

If you want Jenkins to start automatically when your PC is restarted, you could install Jenkins as a Windows service. Documentation: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+as+a+Windows+service

Answer (score 0):

One way is we can deploy `jenkins.war` in Tomcat. In this way, everytime we start tomcat, then Jenkins also gets running.

Another way is to use `java -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=8090`, but we have to hit this command everytime we want to use Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running on Linux you can run the command in background like below:

```
java -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=8090 &
```

If you running in Windows, then you need to register it as Windows service.